# Can't Update to latest PHPMyAdmin when running Nginx and PHP5-FPM

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

At the moment I have a LEMP stack setup running nginx 1.10.0, PHP-FPM 5.6.21 and MySQL 5.5.49

I can install PhpMyAdmin using the default Ubuntu package or via PPA package `ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin`

The problem with both is they are quite out of date, as the default package is 4.0.10 and nijel is 4.3.8

Ideally I would like to get it working with the PPA package `ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin` as that is running the latest version 4.6.1 however whenever I install this PPA and try to run install I get the following errors

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
phpmyadmin : Depends: php but it is not installable
          Depends: php-mysql but it is not installable
          Depends: php-cli but it is not installable
          Depends: php-json but it is not installable
          Depends: php-mbstring but it is not installable
          Depends: php-xml but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-gd but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-bz2 but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-zip but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not going to be installed
```

I have an ansible script that runs and install PhpMyAdmin with no problems, so ideally I'd like to get that working with `ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin`

Comment: have you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should add PHP PECL extensions repository (https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) to system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Than you can try to install phpmyadmin